# Ein beis hamidrash bli chiddush

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study

Rav Daniel Glatstein shlita often quotes the idea of:

> ein beis hamidrash bli chiddush

Meaning, whenever you say a chiddush, over and over, there always is something new to say and to discover.

Where does this idea come from? “ein beis hamidrash bli chiddush” - and what does it mean?

Please cite sources :)

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.3a.15

Comment: @אילפא thanks. And what about the idea that even if you have already said something, there is always something new to discover? Any sources for that? Please feel free to put it into an answer so I can award the points to you.

Comment: כׇּל זְמַן שֶׁאָדָם מְמַשְׁמֵשׁ בָּהּ — מוֹצֵא בָּהּ תְּאֵנִים. אַף דִּבְרֵי תוֹרָה, כׇּל זְמַן שֶׁאָדָם הוֹגֶה בָּהֶן — מוֹצֵא בָּהֶן טַעַם.
whenever a person searches it for figs to eat, he finds figs in it, as the figs on a tree do not ripen all at once, so that one can always find a recently ripened fig, so too, with matters of Torah. Whenever a person meditates upon them, he finds in them new meaning.

https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.54b.1